# How to get iOS user-set device name with Cordova?

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm using the `org.apache.cordova.device` plugin. I see that `device.name` [has been deprecated](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#device.name) a while back in favor of `device.model`. When using device plugin 0.2.12 and iOS 8.1 on iPhone 5S,  `device.name` is `undefined`.

I still need to get the user's device name, like "Jerry's iPhone", so that the user can see which of their devices are using my app. How to do that with Cordova?

Comment: Were you able to get this working?

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet might be modifying the Device plugin (with all the undesired consequences). I was able to get the device name by adding the following line to `deviceProperties` in `./cordova/platforms/ios/[project name]/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.device/CDVDevice.m`:

```
- (NSDictionary*)deviceProperties
{
    UIDevice* device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    NSMutableDictionary* devProps = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:4];
    [devProps setObject:[device name] forKey:@"name"];    // <------------- new line
```

You also need to adjust the corresponding Javascript object in `./cordova/plugins/org.apache.cordova.device/www/device.js`:

```
 channel.onCordovaReady.subscribe(function() {
    me.getInfo(function(info) {
        me.name = info.name;             // <---------- new line
```

`device.name` may have been deprecated and removed from the plugin, but the assigned `name` is still a supported attribute as of the iOS SDK 8.1 [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/name).

Answer (score 0):

The device plugin does not support the name, however there is another plugin that does:

https://github.com/becvert/cordova-plugin-device-name