# Not getting exact device name using cordova plugin

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, cordova-plugins, device

I am using `cordova-plugin-device` for getting device model using following code

```
var deviceModel = device.model;
```

But in `deviceModel` variable I am getting values like **iPhone1,1** or **iPad2,1** which does not let user know actual device model name like **iPhone 4** or **iPad Mini** etc.

I have checked the link https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device/#devicemodel and they have given same there.

My question is how i'll be able to get device name then?

Currently I have implemented a function like

```
       /**
         * Identify the device from model(identifier) 
         * @param: model : model get from device
         * 
         * */
        $scope.identifyDeviceModel = function(model){
            var modelName = "iPhone";
            if(model.indexOf('iPad') != -1){
                modelName = "iPad";
            }
            switch(model){
                case 'iPhone1,1': modelName = 'iPhone';break;
                case 'iPhone1,2': modelName = 'iPhone 3G';break;
                case 'iPhone2,1': modelName = 'iPhone 3GS';break;
                case 'iPad1,1': modelName = 'iPad';break;
                case 'iPad2,1': modelName = 'iPad 2';break;
                case 'iPad3,1': modelName = 'iPad 3rd Gen';break;
                case 'iPhone3,1':
                case 'iPhone3,3': modelName = 'iPhone 4';break;
                case 'iPhone4,1': modelName = 'iPhone 4S';break;
                case 'iPhone5,1': 
                case 'iPhone5,2': modelName = 'iPhone 5';break;
                case 'iPad3,4': modelName = 'iPad';break;
                case 'iPad2,5': modelName = 'iPad Mini';break;
                case 'iPhone5,3':
                case 'iPhone5,4': modelName = 'iPhone 5c';break;
                case 'iPhone6,1':
                case 'iPhone6,2': modelName = 'iPhone 5s';break;
                case 'iPhone7,1': modelName = 'iPhone 6 Plus';break;
                case 'iPhone7,2': modelName = 'iPhone 6';break;
                case 'iPhone8,1': modelName = 'iPhone 6S';break;
                case 'iPhone8,2': modelName = 'iPhone 6S Plus';break;
                case 'iPhone8,4': modelName = 'iPhone SE';break;
            }
            return modelName;
        }
```

But once latest iPhone launches, I have to rework on this again which I don't want. Please let me know any further way to get out of this.

Comment: @Mr.Noody I hope you may have to extend the plugin to achieve this. You have to check out this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573944/how-to-get-ios-user-set-device-name-with-cordova

Comment: @Gandhi that is for user-set device name...not device model name...

Comment: As mentioned you may have to extend the plugin as per your requirement as there is no readymade solution as far as i know

Comment: Ok.... I wish there could be...!!! Anyways... as long as latest iPhone does not the above one will work for me...!!

Comment: Cool. Happy Coding